# imagick solid background not colorizing

Tags: php, image, imagemagick

trying to assign a black background to this thumbnail while it is being scalled.
It always produces a white background even when I change the RGBA values... What am I doign wrong?

````
$imagick->setbackgroundcolor(new ImagickPixel( "rgba(0,0,0,1.00)" ) );
$imagick->thumbnailImage(200, 200, true, true);
$imagick->writeImages(ABSROOT.'/thumbs/'. $fileID.'_Small.jpg' ,true ); ```
````

Comment: Where's the code for the source image? And does the source image have a transparent background (desirable) or a white one?

Comment: Post your input image! Is it already transparent? Does it have an opaque white background?  Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).